# ActionMailer generating multipart email instead of plain html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.0.10 and I have the following Mailer

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
def daily_report
    @stats = some_method
    attachments[@stats.filename] = @stats.to_csv
    mail(:to => receivers, :subject => "some subject goes here") do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

the template for this mail contains some htm:

```
$ ls app/views/admin_mailer | grep daily
daily_report.html.erb
```

But for some reason the email is being rendered as empty

```
class AdminMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  def test_daily_report
    msg = AdminMailer.daily_report
    assert_equal '32', msg.body.to_s.size # this returns 0
    assert_equal 'text/html', msg.mime_type # this also fails
  end
end
```

any idea why its sending text email?

Comment: Try specifying the template file for HTML & text, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views. Then if the render fails you will know. It could be some problem in HTML file also.